# ggplotly with facet_wrap(scales = 'free_y') creates uneven panel widths

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

The following code creates a faceted Plotly plot using ggplotly, where each facet has the same height and width:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

data <- expand.grid(
  measure = paste0('m', 1:6),
  x = seq(as.Date('2017-01-01'), as.Date('2017-10-01'), length.out = 10))

data$y <- runif(nrow(data))

test <- ggplot(
  aes(
    x = x,
    y = y),
  data = data) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~measure)

g <- ggplotly(test)
print(g)
```

[image]

But for a new iteration, I want to allow the y-scales to vary, so I added `scales = 'free_y'`. This causes two problems:

The middle panel in each row becomes narrower than the outer panels, and the data points disappear in panels [2,1] and [2,2], for no clear reason.

```
test <- ggplot(
  aes(
    x = x,
    y = y),
  data = data) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~measure, scales = 'free_y')

g <- ggplotly(test)
print(g)
```

[image]

If I change to `scales = 'free'` instead of `'free_y'`, I get the data points back, but the middle panel in each row is still narrower, and I need to add panel spacing to keep the x-axis labels from getting overlapped:

```
test <- ggplot(
  aes(
    x = x,
    y = y),
  data = data) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~measure, scales = 'free')

g <- ggplotly(test)
print(g)
```

[image]

Is there a good way to keep the panel widths equal with varying y scales?

Comment: Three weeks ago, I opened an issue about the `scales=free_y` problem: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1132

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thanks for confirming this is a known issue!

Comment: Dis issue hit me too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: There is limited workaround for this issue, see github issue tracker.

Comment: Looks like another long-term unresolved ggplotly bug

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Removing the y-axis numbers solved the problem;

```
+theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
```